# SpringBoot package does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot

Getting started in Springboot and the below packages can't be found. I have added both dependencies clicked Maven and reload project and tried rebuilding the project but still no success. Probably a simple fix.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ExampleEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Since Spring Boot v3 you should use `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`

Comment: If you are using java 9 and above you need to update your imports to jakarta package instead of javax. As from java 9 JPA(java persistent api) was replaced by JPL(jakarta persistent layer)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the issue is with your javax imports. The most recent versions of spring, jpa, and many other spring modules have migrated to the jakarta namespace. This means that unless you want to specifically use older versions of your dependencies, most (but not all) javax imports and dependencies need to be changed to jakarta.

https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6